# Flex nowrap container not wrapping child. when the width of those are in mentioned in percentage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that wraps some cards. I have implemented a horizontal scroller with flex(using flex-nowrap). The flex wrapper container is subjected to have a 36px left spacing and a 0px right spacing initially. The catch here is after the last card is scrolled I need to have a 36px right spacing.

here is what I did so far

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: cadetblue;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px 36px;
}

.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: -36px;
}

.scroll-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px -16px;
}


.card {
  height: 250px;
  width: 75%;
  flex: 1 0 75%;
  padding: 0px 16px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll-wrapper">
     <div class="scroll-inner">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have given a negative right margin for the wrapper to make it look like it's flowing from the right.
Once the last element is scrolled/reached I want it to look something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6umvW.png)

One thing I noticed is my scroll-inner(flex-nowrap) is not wrapping up the entire children. I presumed if we have five children each having width 50px. The scroll-inner should show a scrollable width of 250px, Unfortunately, it's not how flex is behaving. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Updating few images that show what I'm really looking for

**During scrolling**

[image]

**After scrolling till the last card**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

.scroll-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi Danill. I have purposefully added a negative right margin to scroll-wrapper, I want the card to flow from the rightmost end without spacing. The issue is, once scrolled and reached the final card, I want that spacing to appear. The below is what I want to be implemented using the CSS grid. I'm looking forward to achieving this using flex
https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/82398fb3e5f4e01e64f08164737a8291

Comment: @Vinu Prasad, I updated my answer, check it please.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @Daniil. Thanks and appreciate your efforts. I think I couldn't convey properly what I'm really looking for. I have updated my question with few images and I think that will add more clarity.

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand, I will reply later

Comment: @VinuPrasad, `.scroll-inner{margin:auto}`? `.scroll-inner:last-child{padding-right: 36px}`?

Comment: @Daniil, the problem with adding padding for the last card is, the content width of the last card will become 296 while the rest will be 316. All cards should have a uniform width

Comment: @VinuPrasad, does .scroll-inner{margin:auto} work?

Comment: @Daniil, I tried that as well, Unfortunately, I need 36px padding towards the end. Here it will take the card padding ie 16px only. Margin-auto also creates some extra space at the start as well. Thanks for the efforts though!

Comment: Sorry, I have no more ideas how to solve your problem, I guess you should repost your question, so that someone who can answer notices it. I can delete my answer though, because maybe people see that there's an answer already and don't try to solve problem

Comment: @Daniil, no worries, Hopefully, I will figure it out someday and will post the answer here. Thanks for all the efforts again, cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! I'm happy to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix and hope this help someone.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: cadetblue;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px 36px;
}

.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: -36px;
}

.scroll-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}


.card {
  height: 250px;
  width: 75%;
  flex: 1 0 75%;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll-wrapper">
     <div class="scroll-inner">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><h2>Card</h2></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please do answer if someone has a better solution!! Thanks